# How we can use clickable property for different icons with row in jetpack compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I want to apply clickable for two different button in two different row in jetpack compose, but I did not find any way to do it, I know we can apply it like that

```
 modifier = Modifier
              .clickable {}
```

for Text or Image, but I have two

> painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon)

and

> painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon2)

in rows, is there any solution it?

```
  class MyActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MyScreen()
        }
    }

}
@Composable
fun MyScreen(

) {

    val context = LocalContext.current


            Column(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {

               MainRow(

                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon)

               )

                MainRow(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon2)
                )
          }
        }
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    painter: Painter
   

) {

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(16.dp),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {

           

            Image(

            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(25.dp),
                


            )

        }
    }
```

Comment: Use different Modifiers for MainRow and then invoke it, try my solution below.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why don't you apply `Modifier.clickable` for each item? Do you need to perform same action on any of two row clicks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set your click listener at the point where you are calling the composable function with Modifier MainRow(), so that different click action can be called.

Add extra parameter Modifier to MainRow()

```
    MainRow(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon),
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
            // Action to perform
        })
    )

    MainRow(
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon2),
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
            // Action to perform
        })
    )
```

Now added that Modifier argument for invoked function to make use of existing Modifier.

```
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    painter: Painter,
    modifier: Modifier
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier.padding(16.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Image(
            painter = painter,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = modifier.size(25.dp))
    }
}
```

Final changes

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    
    val context = LocalContext.current

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        MainRow(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon),
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
                // Action to perform
            })
        )

        MainRow(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon2),
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
                // Action to perform
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: it is work for row, tnx but for image buuton, I will add where? like when I click the image icon , it must be work

Answer (score 7):

Pass onClick to MainRow:

```
@Composable
fun MainRow(
    painter: Painter,
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = onClick),
    ){}
}
```

Comment: tnx for ur answer, but it is for all row, I have 2 different icons, how I will do for them separately

Comment: You can use  Modifier.clickable on Image element in the same way

Comment: can you show example for this one for example, painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon) or painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_icon2)